# Split text files

Tags: java

First of all I am new to Java.

I am trying to use the Split() function on a user specified txt file.
It should split the files using space to output a array of Strings.
I am using JFileChooser but I dont know how to perform Split on the selected txt file. I am using a Scanner to do this.

Please if someone can make the code finished, for some reason I cant get my head around it :-/

I have made it so far:

```
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            ".txt and .java files", "txt", "java");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);


            int code = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner input;
            try {
                input = new Scanner(selectedFile);

                while (input.hasNext()) {

                String[] splits = input.next().split(" ");
                } 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


}
            }
```

Comment: What is `f`? Also, why is it used as an exception too?

Comment: I want it to be the selected txt file from Jfilechooser so it can split the files into a array. I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to split the input by the space character, then include a string with a space instead of an empty string.  Replace

```
String[] splits = f.split("");
```

with

```
String[] splits = f.split(" ");  // One space
```

As others have pointed out, `f` isn't declared in your block.  You'll have to declare it as a `String` and use your `Scanner` to read input into `f`, *then* use `split`.

Comment: @PremGenError Yes, that would be necessary if there is more than one space between the inputted filenames, or other whitespace.

Comment: But I still need to set the selected file from Jfilechooser to the variable f so it can split the files. I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.split("");
```

or

```
f.split("[\\s]+");
```

to be safe with tabs and double spaces.

Comment: I am with you guys so far, and have cleaned my code a little. Please if someone could make the code, I just cant get my head around it, for some reason. @Mike ?

Answer (score 0):

What is `f`? It's not declared anywhere, except as an Exception after having being used earlier, which makes no sense.

Your while loop should be written as this:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {

    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] splits = line.split(" ");
    // put the result of split somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (input.hasNext()) {

        String[] splits = f.split("");

        input.next();
    }

    System.out.println(f);
```

First of all, `splits` is never used. Second of all, `input.next()` is never stored in a variable. Also, I have no idea what `f` is. Try something like this:

```
    while (input.hasNext()) {

        String[] splits = input.next().split(" ");
        someList.add(splits);

    }
```

You could declare `someList` as something like `new ArrayList<String[]>()`.